# Plural or singular? After the word "any"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, any

I often get confused which one to use after any. Or are both correct?

> Do you have any **room** available on March 22nd?

> Do you have any **rooms** available on March 22nd?

Answer (score 1):

In this use of "any", in a question, the plurality distinguishes between mass and count nouns.

Hence, "any room" means "any space". You could ask:

> Is there any room for my backpack? I want to set it down.

Whereas "any rooms" is the count noun you want to use:

> Are there any rooms available? I want to book one for this weekend.

That said, the singular would be understandable with enough context. It would just be less likely given that the plural is unambiguous.

> Do you have any room that sleeps six people? *(I am forced to reinterpret "room" when I hear "sleeps".)

Note that this is not true of "any" in a declarative sentence. These sentences both refer to the count noun "hotel room" despite being in the singular:

> Any room will do, as long as it has a bed!

> I don't know of any room that includes a hot tub.

Comment: Thank you  so much!